# How do I protect myself from friendly-fired spells?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I crafted a very potent Firaga spell and, while liking Noctis' current setup, I gave the spell to Prompto. I was in a grassy area, fighting creatures who's weakness was fire, and the next thing I know *Operation Firestorm* commenced, which dealt a huge chunk damage that nearly costed me the fight.

If I cast a spell as Noctis, I can strategically cast spells and wait for an opening before casting. If I give it to either Prompto, Ignis, or Gladiolus, they appear to cast spells blindly, as long as it is the enemy's weakness.

Is there a way to protect myself from friendly-fired spells, or do I need to hope for the best that I do not get killed?

Comment: "Operation Firestorm" reminded me of [this](https://youtu.be/tbTBIV5Dsjc?t=4m52s) greatness.

Comment: I can't get the link because I'm on the app, but there's another question about holiday dlc, and the aanswer mentions an item that protects your party from friendly fire magic damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, giving your party members magic is like giving your companions Fat Men in Fallout 4. They use them with no regard to your location, so you'll typically be caught in the blast.

The same goes for when *you* cast. In fact, until recently, me using spells typically meant death to all my party members. Swinging your sword at your party members elicits a "Hey! Watch where you swing that thing!" response, but doesn't actually damage them. Using magic near them will pretty much kill them, if you use a powerful enough spell, so watch out.

My advice would just be to *not* ever give your party members spells, unfortunately.

Comment: This is pretty much what I had gathered also, but I wasn't sure if there were other solutions. Thanks!

Comment: With all but the limit break spells, ive never really killed my friends with magic, however they do sometimes take significant damage and stumble around. However, its never stopped me. If i need a spell, then my friends arent being very helpful anyway

Answer (score 4):

If you have the season pass.

The holiday DLC has an accessory called "Ring of Resistance" which makes your party immune to friendly fire.

Comment: Did some research on the item. You say "immune", but other sources say "resistant" (meaning some protection). Can you clarify that?

Comment: I understood it to be "fully resistant" but havent tested myself. I can try to test it later today after work and see how it actually functions.

Comment: I do state you need the season pass, and its part of the Holiday DLC.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you can and should give party members spells, but much later in the game.

Because you can't really do much about the inherent fratricide in FF15 with regard to magic outside of wearable items (hey, you can boost that to wear three at a time, and there's always New Game +), but you can craft spells that do damage to enemies and heal friends, mainly the caster, but there are a few late game items that you can get a spell to heal the group while hurting the enemy.

the fourth slot is your money maker...use it.

And, if there's some residual yet unasked question regarding why 'Reflect' isn't something in the game...It's because the caster would either martyr themselves and take an exponential number of hits to number cast, or it would be insta-kill and like calling Knights of the Round with Mimic going off.

Lastly, pay attention to stats with equipment. Many of the weapons have a degree of stat boosts which negate some magic damage. I have never killed anyone with spells and I drop Multicast X 5 Firaga + Thundaga like a hot rock.

Tip: they say fools rush in, be the fool. Target a specific enemy and let loose prior to your party getting all grabby with the real-estate.